# Converting DateTimes that are near DayLight Savings time?

Tags: c#, dst, datetime-conversion

I'm working on software that runs reports for GPS devices that are running 24/7/365. Part of the report output requires that we convert our stored database times (kept in Central Standard Time) to user timers (any requested time zone). Twice a year we run into an issue with DST when people run reports that start before and finish after the time change. It fails at one line:

```
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateToConvert, DatabaseTime, UserTime);
```

`dateToConvert` is a `DateTime` to be converted. `DatabaseTime` and `UserTime` are both `TimeZoneInfo` objects. I'm not doing anything tricky or complicated but DateTimes near the DST time change throw exceptions. Such as `3/10/2013 2:02:11 AM` even though it's being "converted" from Central Time to Central Time.

What is the best method for handling DateTimes near DST time changes?

Comment: It's probably more of an overhaul than you want, but it might be better to store all dates/times in GMT (since CST undergoes the DST change, there are discontinuities in the scale that aren't there in GMT) and only convert for display purposes (as well as maybe converting input parameters).

Comment: If I were starting over from scratch, I would definitely do that. I like the idea of the data being as neutral as possible and I think that'd be the way to do it.

Comment: Just to confirm: Is it possible to store `3/10/2013 2:02:11 AM` in your database, given that it is in the skipped hour?

Comment: @JoelRondeau That is a question I'm definitely going to have to ask my coworker who's worked on that part of the system. That DateTime IS actually in our system, I just need to figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion should work properly as the time is not truly junk, as Hans stated, rather it is just non-adjusted (a term I just invented). `3/10/2013 2:02:11 AM CDT == 3/10/2013 8:02:11 AM UTC == 3/10/2013 3:02:11 AM CDT`...they are ALL semantically equivalent. If you do not believe me, do the conversion at [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com) and see they all equate (round to nearest 5 minutes for their calculator though). Whether .NET code will allow this semantic equivalence, I have not tried it because I am not in front of my dev box currently.

UPDATE #1:

Run the following code on a computer set to CST time zone:

```
using System;

namespace TimeZoneSample
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            DateTime t = DateTime.Parse("3/10/2013 2:02:11 AM");
            Console.WriteLine(t);
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToUniversalTime());
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToUniversalTime().ToLocalTime());
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following console output:

```
3/10/2013 2:02:11 AM
3/10/2013 8:02:11 AM
3/10/2013 3:02:11 AM
```

Proof that my original explanation is correct. ***quod erat demonstrandum***

Comment: I agree and am completely with you but .Net's DateTime doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: As per your edit, that works when I pause the debugger and insert it into the Watch list, but when the code actually tries to execute `return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateToConvert.ToUniversalTime().ToLocalTime(), DatabaseTime, UserTime);` I get an error saying that `DatabaseTime` needs to be `TimeZoneInfo.Local`. I don't know if that's an acceptable assumption to make in our system.

Comment: I talked with my team. Turns out it's a safe enough assumption since we host our own servers.

Answer (score 4):

You have garbage in your database, 3/10/2013 2:02:11 AM never existed.  The minute after 1:59 AM that morning was 3:00 AM, the clock was moved by an hour.  .NET is not going to put up with that junk date.

You will need to find out how that garbage timestamp ended up in your dbase.  Clearly a conversion of a time from one timezone to another that disregards daylight savings rules, like active in one but not the other, is a highly likely source of that garbage.  If you can't fix your dbase to use UTC then at least do it in your code.  First going to UTC in the one timezone and then back to local time in the other.  Use the TimeZoneInfo class, ConvertTimeFrom/ToUtc methods.

Comment: The backend code that takes GPS entries and pushes them into the database is all written in VB6 (I hate it and I can't wait until we push our C# changes) and I'm thinking that maybe our VB6 didn't pay enough attention to DST during it's calculations.

Comment: Yes, it is **very** unlikely that a VB6 backend would get that right.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem. I fixed it by adding a new GMT time column. This allowed the application to work with the original data and any fixes to work with GMT. Then I changed the application so that any code that was having problems with daylight savings would access this new column. Also, as time went on, I re-pointed any code that was used for calculation to this new column leaving the displays to work with the old column. It's not elegant, but it works and it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow one of the other answers if that's at all possible - you want to fix this properly. If your time is incorrect during the fall transition it won't generate an exception, it's just going to randomly be an hour off.

There's a workaround to get you out of your current jam. Since it's only the missing hour during the spring that will cause the exception, you can catch the exception and add an hour into the time before repeating the conversion.

Comment: I've been toying with that for the past half hour as a quick fix.